Spring boot application won't start after adding keycloak integration
i am introducing the keycloak token mechanism in my application and after adding a custom JwtTokenConverter and the securityConfig my app won't start with this error. Before that the app worked. I read that it could be a problem related to a dependancies conflict, but i didin't add any dependancies to the project before and after adding the changes above.
Error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:429) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.datotoweb.DaTotoWebApplication.main(DaTotoWebApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.PrePostMethodSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1710) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/authorization/method/AuthorizationAdvisor
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3601) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2686) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationAdvisor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

Pom:
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DaTotoWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DaTotoWeb</name>
    <description>DaTotoWeb</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>annotationProcessor</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

JwtTokenConverter:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimNames;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Component
public class JwtTokenConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>
{
    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    @Value("${jwt.auth.converter.principle-attribute}")
    private String principleAttribute;
    @Value("${jwt.auth.converter.resource-id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt source)
    {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream
                .concat(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(source).stream(),
                        extractResourceRoles(source).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(source, authorities, getPrincipleClaimName(source));
    }

    private String getPrincipleClaimName(Jwt source)
    {
        String claimName = JwtClaimNames.SUB;
        if (principleAttribute != null)
            claimName = principleAttribute;
        return source.getClaim(claimName);
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractResourceRoles(Jwt source)
    {
        Map<String, Object> resourceAccess;
        Map<String, Object> resource;
        Collection<String> resourceRoles;
        if (source.getClaim("resource_access") == null)
            return Set.of();
        resourceAccess = source.getClaim("resource_access");
        if (resourceAccess.get(resourceId) == null)
            return Set.of();
        resource = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get(resourceId);
        resourceRoles = (Collection<String>) resource.get("roles");
        return resourceRoles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}

SecurityConfig:
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.datotoweb.support.components.JwtTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig
{

    private final JwtTokenConverter jwtTokenConverter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth ->
                oauth.jwt(jwt  ->
                        jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtTokenConverter)));
        http.sessionManagement(sm ->
                sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }
}


You are using the incorrect version of spring-security-core namely 6.2.4. It does not have the class org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationAdvisor
You should be using 6.3.1, which matches the spring-boot-starter-parent:3.3.1 that you are using.
Remove the version tags for spring-security-core so you rely on the springboot managed versions and the container start will get past this error.
Try to avoid using specified versions unless the dependency has vulnerabilities. I suggest you also remove the version tags for commons-lang3 & tomcat-embed-jasper unless there is good reason to deviate from the spring-boot recommended version.
This dependency mismatch was always there. It looks like (not absolutely sure) you exposed the mismatch when you used @Component called SecurityConfig.

that was the problem, thanks mate
